# Looping on bottom of fabric while sewing - even after adjusting the tension

Tags: sewing, sewing-machine

We have a Brother XN1700 and have been hitting some problems with looping appearing on the bottom of the fabric. We've tried the following, per the instruction manual and some guides on the internet:

1. Decreasing the tension
2. Increasing the tension (just in case we were confused)
3. Rethreading the bobbin and the spool
4. Removing and refitting the presser foot holder and the presser foot
5. Checked the bobbin hook for any signs of burring

We've never broken a needle on it and the problem seems to have come on gradually in the past few weeks.

Anyone have any thoughts on what could be wrong? I'm happy to disassemble it a bit if needed.

Comment: Just to check, when you rethreaded the spool, you raised the presser foot first?

Comment: Note especially the suggestion to clean the entire bobbin area from accumulated fuzz. It doesn't seem like it would make any difference, but somehow it can.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem and it helped me to sew a few stitches turning the hand wheel with the bobbin compartment open so I could see how the top thread moved around the bobbin case and got stuck there. The loops are usually caused by the top thread still being stuck somewhere around the bobbin case while the machine already pulls it tight. When the thread finally comes loose, the thread isn't tightened anymore, which leaves a loop behind.